# How to pass data to functional component?

Tags: reactjs

As part of React course I'm making a dummy eshop and want to pass products from state of one component to functional component and display product properties there. How to pass data from state to stateless component?

I've set up a component ProductList which stores the products (fetched from api) and ProductDetail which is supposed to show the details (find the product by id and show it's descr, img etc).
I've set up App.js which has two Routes - to List and to Detail.

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>E-Commerce app</h1>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ProductList} />
        <Route path="/:productId" component={ProductDetail} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

ProductList.js:

```
class ProductList extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    products: [],
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const products = await getProducts()

    this.setState({ products: products.data, isLoading: false })
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, products } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {isLoading && '...'}
        {products && (
          <ul>
            {products.map(item => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <Link to={`${item.id}`}>
                  <h2>{item.attributes.name}</h2>
                  <img
                    src={item.attributes.image_url}
                    width="60"
                    alt={item.attributes.description}
                  />
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

ProductDetail.js:

```
const ProductDetail = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Product ID: {match.params.productId}</p>
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <p>Product name: </p>
      <p>Product description: </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the ProductList component's state, and as i have understood you want to display one product detail in another component after clicking the link, right ?

When switching the route your component will unmount and therefore you lose data.

In order to do that you need to do some state management like Redux, MobX or other state management libraries or you can use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which is a feature that has been introduced lately in React.

Answer (score 0):

You will need another request on the details page `/:productId`.

Keep in mind that if a user go straight to the `/:productId` route the product data will not exist, this is why you need a request here.

To optimize  you can use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or a lib like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to manage/store the data. So you can check first if the data of `productId` exists in the store before doing a new request.

Answer (score 0):

First change **Link** like below

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: `${item.id}`,
  state: {
    productObject: item
  }
}}>
```

Then change **ProductDetail** component params.

```
const ProductDetail = ({ match,location })
```

Finally read **Product Name** like this.

```
<p>Product name:{location.state.productObject.attributes.name} </p>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Thanks